# Stack arrays in sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I read linewise `data` from a file and I want to store them in an `array`.

EDIT: The data cannot be read with `loadtxt()`.

So I do it like this:

```
data = array([])
for frame in frames:
    # ....
    # get some lines and make some calculations e.g. final result is
    # line = array([1, 2, 3, 4])
    # ....
    if data.size == 0:
        data = line
    else:
        data = vstack( (data, line) )
```

This works fine, but the `if`-clausel make the solution just look ugly. I wonder if there is a possibility to get ride of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html ?

Comment: Using `data = vstack((data, line)) if data else line`?

Comment: @Bakuriu The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Maybe: data = vstack((data, line)) if data.size else line. Looks better, but still with the same issue of the "if".

Comment: It is better to first append to a list and then use `np.concatenate` (or its specialized derivatives) for speed reasons.

Comment: For the `vstack` problem itself, the solution is to use `data = np.empty((0,4))`, but using a temporary list is probably better (or best you already know the arrays size and just fill it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of elements in `line` is fixed and you just want to avoid an "ugly" solution, you can do this:

```
data = []
for f in frames:
    # do your calculation
    # line = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    data += line
data = np.array(data).reshape((-1,4))
```

Comment: Yes exactly! This is a "beautiful" solution. ^^